# N: Ignoring file 'yarn.lis' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

Tags: linux, debian-based, debian-buster

I am using Linux MX 19 based on Debian 10
When I make an update by terminal
        sudo apt-get update
I see this problem
        All packages are up to date.
        N: Ignoring file 'yarn.lis' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/'     as it has an invalid    filename extension

how to fixed this error ?

Answer (score 1):

The file extension `.lis` is not supported in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, rename the file to `yarn.list`.

From `man 5 sources.list`:

> **SOURCES.LIST.D**
>
> The /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory provides a way to add sources.list entries in separate files. Two different file
> formats are allowed as described in the next two sections. **Filenames need to have either the extension .list or .sources
> depending on the contained format.** The filenames may only contain letters (a-z and A-Z), digits (0-9), underscore (_), hyphen
> (-) and period (.) characters. Otherwise APT will print a notice that it has ignored a file, unless that file matches a
> pattern in the Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently configuration list - in which case it will be silently ignored.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Related:

- [Yarn Installation Debian / Ubuntu](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#debian-stable)